# update div/section by html (or php) after clicking on link on different div/section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, hyperlink

I would like to update a div/section of a web page as a result of clicking on a link from another section of the web page

My html code so far is like this: and I stuck on how to complete the href tags and the content section so that links are tied to the content section/division.  Also is it possible for address bar to reflect the content being viewed (depending on the links clicked) rather than being stuck in address of the original web page?

Edit:
Just to be clear:  I would like to load html into a div upon clicking any links

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example PAGE</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- top header bar -->
<section id="header">
<div id="top_Nav" style="color: #FFFFFF; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;text-shadow:10px 10px 10px blue">
<font size="6"><center>Title</center></font>
</div>
</section>


<section id="Menu">
<div id="navigation">
<div id="menu">
<p<ul><font color=#FFFFFF face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a><b>Dashboard</b></a></font></ul>
<ul><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="./dashboard/Display_global.php"<b>Dashboard</b></a></font></ul>
<ul><li><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="./dashboard/graphs/metric_barchart.html" target="myContent"><b>MDV Bar Chart</b></a></font></ul>
    </p>

<p<ul><font color=#FFFFFF face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a><b>Spitfire I</b></a></font></ul>
            <ul><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="qaweb_sf1/codec/Codec.php" target="myContent"><b>Sfcodec</a></font></ul>
            <ul><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="qaweb_sf1/ats/ats.html" target="myContent">Spitfire I - ATS</a></font></ul>
    <ul><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="qaweb_sf1/latest_sf1dac.html" target="myContent">SF1 DAC</a></font></ul>
    <ul><li><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="qaweb_sf1/dac_db/Dac.php" target="myContent">SF1 DAC DB</a></font></ul>
    <ul><li><li><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><a href="qaweb_sf1/decoder/Front.php" target="myContent">SF1 Decoder</a></font></ul>
 </div>
 </div>

 </section>

 <section id=Content>
 <div id="content"> Some content
 </div>
 </section>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: your request is unclear... would you like to load page into the div on click or just add html to specific div? Please specify your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved it:

```
<?php   
 $page_title = "page title";
 $css_link = '<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>';
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/banner.php");
?>

<section id="Menu">
<div id="navigation">
<div id="menu">
  <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Menu.php");
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</secion>
<section id="Content">
<div id="content">
<base target="_blank" />
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And now I have changed all the pages to .php and have the following template:

```
<?php   
 $page_title = "soemthing to set page title by top_nav";
 $css_link = '<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css"/>';
 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/banner.php");
?>
<section id="Menu">
<div id="navigation">
<div id="menu">
<?php 
  include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Menu.php");
?>
</div>
</div>
</secion>
<section id="Content">
<div id="content">
<br>
Content Here!
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

So now I am reloading everything but the look and feel is mantained, so for a small website, it probably is adequate but I hope there is a more elegant solution to this.